# Request Dispatcher skipping the url after question mark

Tags: url, requestdispatcher

Iam trying to call a request dispatcher from a servlet with the following url but the request dispatcher is not properly forming the url
Iam doing it in the following way

```
RequestDispatcher rd1 = request.getRequestDispatcher("http://obieehost/analytics/saw.dll?Logoff");
        logger.info("calling request dispatcher");      
        rd1.include(request, response);
```

since it is not forming the url properly it gives me in the log

No resource found for http://obieehost/analytics/saw.dll

how can i make request dispatcher to take proper url...

Answer (score 0):

That is because, the request dispatcher will consider everything after the "?" to be parameters. And before that "?" is the path.

The log message tells you that there is no resource for the path you provided. Because it cannot be found at all, the parameters don't matter, so they are also not important to be in the log.